# Pinned tab on Google Chrome has a rippling or highlighting effect

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

On Google Chrome I have a tab with twitter.com on it and it's show a "rippling" effect. Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image: non state] [image: tab with highlight ripple].

You can see the lighter area at the top of the tab to the right of the bird and then to the left.

It moves from right to left and then jumps back to the right. Why is this happening?

It also does it for the tab with Google Reader on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This behavior happens only with pinned tabs. Some web services update the page content in real-time and the part of the update is changing the title of the window. Since the tab is pinned, there's no way for you to see the change in the title, so Chrome engineers created this subtle notification.

Comment: Yes, indeed. For the twitter tab the title is changing to (n) Twitter... where n is the number of new tweets. Just clicking on the tab and then clicking away gets rid of the rippling.

Comment: It isn't "subtle" at all, because the human eye is especially sensitive to peripheral motion.

Comment: Chrome uses a timer most likely triggered from when the pinned tab was last activated.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the images you provided, but I suspect it is the notification that the tab has updated/has new content. This would especially make sense with Reader and Twitter. eg. when the Twitter page updates to say "There are __ new tweets"

Comment: It looks like your answer was truncated.

Comment: That's odd, but thank you - I fixed it!