# Why do Chrome tabs have blue dots on them?

Tags: google-chrome

Why do some of my Chrome tabs have a blue dot on them like this?
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This means that the title has changed. Chrome used to indicate this with a more subtle effect as described in this question: [Pinned tab on Google Chrome has a rippling or highlighting effect](https://superuser.com/questions/444421/pinned-tab-on-google-chrome-has-a-rippling-or-highlighting-effect)

It can also mean that a dialog is open on that page, such as an alert or print dialog.

Comment: Title change blue dot was removed in 2018 [1]. The only remaining cause is that there's a dialog (e.g. JavaScript `alert`, URL Protocol launch permission prompt, print preview) showing on the background tab and it wants attention.

[1] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482776#c38

Answer (score 3):

It means that there is a change of status on that page. The page has changed.

Answer (score 3):

It would also show up in case there is an [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) popup.

To view this in action, open 2 tabs. In the first page open [console](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console#chrome) and type:

```
setTimeout(()=>{alert('hello')},5000);
```

and press enter.
Then navigate to 2nd tab. After `5 sec`, you will see a blue dot on the first tab.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail as to what an `alert` pop up is?